# php - add comma thousands separator but remove trailing zeros

Tags: php

I am trying to use PHP to format a number to

1. Remove all trailing zeros
2. Add a comma for the thousands separator
3. List two decimal points, assuming that they are not zeros

I tried this, but its not doing exactly what I am trying to achieve:

```
$prices[$title]['reg_price'] = (float)number_format($membership->sell_price, 2, ".", "");
$prices[$title]['three_year_price'] = (float)number_format($membership->attributes[$aid]->options[$three_year_oid]->price, 2, ".", "");
```

I had found that I could strip trailing zeros by casting the number to a float. However, I found that I needed to tell number_format NOT to use the thousands comma separator, because otherwise, when casting 1,500.00 to a float, the result was 1.

So, in summary, I want my code to change 1500.00 to 1,500, 150.00 to 150, and 19.99 to 19.99. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function parseCurrency($value) {
    if ( intval($value) == $value ) {
        $return = number_format($value, 0, ".", ",");
    }
    else {
        $return = number_format($value, 2, ".", ",");
        /*
        If you don't want to remove trailing zeros from decimals,
        eg. 19.90 to become: 19.9, remove the next line
        */
        $return = rtrim($return, 0);
    }

    return $return;
}

$prices[] = parseCurrency(1500.00);
$prices[] = parseCurrency(1500.10);
$prices[] = parseCurrency(1500.1);
$prices[] = parseCurrency(1500);
$prices[] = parseCurrency(123.53);
$prices[] = parseCurrency(1224323.53);
$prices[] = parseCurrency(19.99);

print_r($prices);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1,500
    [1] => 1,500.1
    [2] => 1,500.1
    [3] => 1,500
    [4] => 123.53
    [5] => 1,224,323.53
    [6] => 19.99
)
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need (and yes, I would remove the rtrim line). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This inserts commas, rounds to 2 decimal places, removes trailing zeroes, and removes trailing '.':

```
rtrim(rtrim(number_format($value,2),0),'.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
ltrim($var, '0');
```

to remove the leading `0`. And

```
rtrim($var, '0');
```

to remove the trailing.

Comment: This doesn't work perfectly - it still leaves a decimal at the end of the number, and I still need to do a check on the number to see if the last character is a . , and if so, remove it

Answer (score -1):

For replacing "." to "," u can use a function :

```
function replace_dot($value) {
    $str = str_replace('.', ',', $value);
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: this also needs some additonal code: this would turn 19.99 into 19,99

Comment: you can use the function where you feel comfortable, in the case of 19.99 just do not use it. or you can add `if (strlen($str) !=5) { //do the statement replace }`

Comment: But how are your planning on using this function anyways? What is the $value in your example? I can create the numbers 1500, or 1,500.00, and your function doesn't help in either.

Comment: Of cource I do. I'm just saying, my code produces 1500 or 1,500.00, and inputing either of those into your function would not give me 1,500

Comment: @Alex, did you even read what he wanted? 1) Remove all trailing zeros, 2) Add a comma for the thousands separator, 3) List two decimal points, assuming that they are not zeros. Your suggestions does none of them, only replaces decimal from . (dot) into , (comma), not removing trailing zeros or adding , (comma) as a thousand separator.